# Disable Event Receiver on Datasheet Editing

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, itemupdated

I have an ItemUpdated Event bound to a list and do not want it to fire when the List item is edited in Datasheet view. Is there a way to detect if the User is editing through the Datasheet?

Answer (score 0):

You have DisableEventFiring in SharePoint use `EventFiringEnabled = false;`  I am not able to understand in what context you mean to use it but yes Event firing can be disabled [Check here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/programmatically-disable-event-firing-on-list-item-update-in/) for more details. Alternatively you can declare a boolean variable and use as below

```
bool isEdited = false; 
protected override void onItemEdited(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
   isEdited=true;
}
 protected override void onItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
   if(!isEdited)
   {
      //your code
   }
}
```

Comment: yup, I know about that flag but I guess the question is more geared towards detecting Datasheet mode from the server